# How to write a file on the resource(windows or Linux machine) provisioned by Terraform

Tags: file, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I would like to know if there is a way we can write a file to the Linux or Windows machine provisioned by Terraform.
Example, i would like to write a file to D:\temp\myfile.txt which should have the information which i can pass from main.tf.

I tried using the below

```
  provisioner "file" {
      content = EOF
 this myfile which is created using Terraform and will have all data which i write
      EOF 
      destination = "/app/iac/myfile.txt" 
    }
```

but with this when i run Terraform init or terraform plan i get the following error

```
Error: Unknown root level key: provisioner
```

Comment: The provisioner needs to be attached to a resource. Either the resource that creates the instance or a null resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@ydaetskcoR but can you please help me with more details, i am very new to Terraform.
My requirement is to write a file on the server which is provisioned, can you tell me if there is a way to do that.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html and you need do your own job by yourself.